# Rotate a bitmap stored in a 1D array

Tags: c#, arrays, bitmap

***Edit:*** The second code example is the right answer. My problem was outside the bitmap rotation itself so the second code example is the answer to the question in the title.

I'm trying to rotate a bitmap stored in a 1D array (_pixelData). I just can't seem to get it working. Could someone point me to the right direction or give an example solution.

The image is 320 x 240 pixels and stored in a 1D array (first 320 values represent the first line in the bitmap, the next 320 the next line and so on).

I don't want to write it to a writeablebitmap rotate it there and convert it bact to int array. I want to operate the int array. The reason for this is that the source comes from camera as ARGB data and I want to keep this simple.

Here's what I've got (doesn't work. The result is a broken image where the vertical lines don't meet)

```
// Rotate the data for Portait Mode
            int height = 320;
            int width = 240;
            int[] _pixelDataRotated = new int[width* height];
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                    _pixelDataRotated[x * height + height - y - 1] = _pixelData[x + y * width];
            }
```

This is how I've done it and it does to rotation. **This is the answer.**

```
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
      for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
         _pixelDataRotated[y + x * height] = _pixelData[x + y * width];
```

Comment: Could you provide an example (source result)?  "Rotate" can mean a lot of things.

Comment: @ScottHunter Forgot to add that I'm trying to rotate it 90 degrees (exactly).

Comment: When you rotate a 320x240 image, it becomes a 240x320 image; have you taken this into account?

Comment: Thanks! I had taken it to account but only for passing the value further. I forgot to change it for the debug image and that's why the image lines were cut in the wrong places. For the record my second code example is the one I'm currently using and it does the job just fine. I'll edit the message.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was the answer. It was in my original question as an example but I thought it was broken but it turned out that the actual problem was in the bitmap image dimensions and not the algorithm for the 90 degree rotation itself.

```
// _pixelData is the source array _pixelDataRotated the target array
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
     _pixelDataRotated[y + x * height] = _pixelData[x + y * width];
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code twice for you? For me it just flips the picture back instead of rotating it another 90 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

x - source.
y - roteted;

```
        var x = new[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
        var y = new int[12];
        var width = 4;
        var height = 3;

        for (var i = 0; i < width; i++)
            for (var j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                y[i * height + j] = x[j * width + i];
            }
```