# Rotating a 1d RGBA array

Tags: javascript, arrays, rotation, p5.js

I'm working with a 1D pixel RGBA array that looks like this:

```
pixelArray =[0,0,0,255,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255];
```

What this pixelArray corresponds to when drawn is 2 black pixels and 4 white pixels:

```
BB
WW
WW
```

My goal is to rotate the order of the pixels inside the array so the picture when drawn will look like

```
BWW  or WWB
BWW     WWB
```

Which means I need to convert the pixelArray to

```
rotatedPixelArray = [0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255]
```

The above example is just that, an example. The actual rgba could represent any image and could have a length of 1 million +.
I've tried various algorithms [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27316393/rotate-a-bitmap-stored-in-a-1d-array), and converting to a 2d array and then rotating and flattening (which does work) but i'd like to avoid this because speed/memory is an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out, in my case it needed to be rotated left or right. The code I used is as followed:

```
function rotatePixelArray(pixelArray,w,h) {
  var rotatedArray = [];

  for (var x=0;x<w;x++) {
    for(var y=0;y<h;y++) {
      index = (x+y*w)*4;
      rotatedArray.push(pixelArray[index]);
      rotatedArray.push(pixelArray[index+1]);
      rotatedArray.push(pixelArray[index+2]);
      rotatedArray.push(pixelArray[index+3]);
    }
  }

  return rotatedArray;
}
```

To rotate it back you can pass in switched w,h variables.

Comment: I tried it, and it rotates great. Only thing is that, it mirrors the image during rotation, any idea how to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could be helpful in p5.js for 90 degrees rotation (left and right) (the previous suggested solution seems to have a little 'asymmetric' error):

```
function rotateRight(img){

  var w = img.width;
  var h = img.height;
  var index, indexr;
  var img2 = createImage(w, h);

  img.loadPixels();
  img2.loadPixels();

  indexr = 0;

  for (let x = 0; x < w; x++) {

    for(let y = h - 1; y >= 0; y--) {

      index = (x+y*w)*4;
      img2.pixels[indexr] = img.pixels[index];
      img2.pixels[indexr + 1] = img.pixels[index+1];
      img2.pixels[indexr + 2] = img.pixels[index+2];
      img2.pixels[indexr + 3] = img.pixels[index+3];

      indexr += 4;

    }
  }

  img.updatePixels();
  img2.updatePixels();

  return img2;

}


function rotateLeft(img){

  var w = img.width;
  var h = img.height;
  var index, indexr;
  var img2 = createImage(w, h);

  img.loadPixels();
  img2.loadPixels();

  indexr = 0;

  for (let x = w - 1; x >= 0; x--) {

    for(let y = 0; y < h; y++) {

      index = (x+y*w)*4;
      img2.pixels[indexr] = img.pixels[index];
      img2.pixels[indexr + 1] = img.pixels[index+1];
      img2.pixels[indexr + 2] = img.pixels[index+2];
      img2.pixels[indexr + 3] = img.pixels[index+3];

      indexr += 4;

    }
  }

  img.updatePixels();
  img2.updatePixels();

  return img2;

}
```